# How do I turn off the bluetooth at the start of the system?

Tags: bluetooth

How do I turn off the default bluetooth power on at the start of the system?

Answer (score -1):

Go to System Settings > Applications > Startup, and make a Custom Command:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```